# Tensorflow object-detection API Num class

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I would like to know if the values of num_classes in Tensorflow object-detection API can affects the model performance. 
For example , lets say I am training the model to detect only one object(say human) but in the the num_classes I set it 20. Does incorrect number of num_classes will have affects on the model performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not critical if you set `num_classes` to be higher than the actual number of classes (it only makes some tensors/variables a bit larger), but it is critical if you set it to be lower. the first case shouldn't affect the model performance.